# Angular 4 How to Unit Test Subscribe inside Observable

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

I'm trying to test a service I'm using for my Angular CLI project. I've tested all the functions in it except those with a subscribe and the subscribe is giving me trouble. Please help. How should I test this function?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Injectable()
export class BuildService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  index() {
    let o = new Observable( observer => {
      this.httpClient.get("/api/build").subscribe(builds => {
        this.setInitialResultsValue(builds);
        observer.next(builds);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
    return o;
  }
}
```

Current try at a test:

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { XHRBackend, ResponseOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { BuildService } from './build.service';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

describe('BuildService (MockBackend)', () => {
  let mock, service;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [ BuildService, {
        provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend
      }],
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject([BuildService, XHRBackend], (s, b) => {
    service = s;
    mock = b;
  }));

  it('should subscribe all values correctly', () => {
    let o = service.index();
    let response: any;
    spyOn(service, "index").and.returnValue(Observable.of(response));
    expect(response).toEqual(o);
  });

});
```

And current error message I'm getting:

```
Expected undefined to equal Observable({ _isScalar: false, _subscribe: Function }).
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

UPDATED ANSWER THANKS TO Buczkowski & JB Nizet

Function:

```
index() {
    return this.httpClient.get('/api/build').do(builds => this.setInitialResultsValue(builds));
  }
```

Test:

```
it('should subscribe all builds correctly', inject([HttpClient], (httpClient: HttpClient) => {
  spyOn(httpClient, "get").and.returnValue(Observable.of(builds));
  service.index().subscribe(response => {
    expect(response).toEqual(builds);
  });
}));
```

Comment: You're spying the method you want to test. That makes no sense. If you want to test index() you need to call it in your test. You code is also more complex than it should be. Just return the observable returned by HttpClient: `return this.httpClient.get('/api/build').do(builds => this.setInitialResultsValue(builds));`. Thenread the guide explaining how to test HttpClient: https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests

Comment: Wow, thanks! I don't know how I never came across "do"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
it('description', inject([HttpClient], (httpClient: HttpClient) => {
    spyOn(httpClient.get).and.returnValue(Observable.of([])); // Some array with builds objects?
    component.index().subscribe(builds => {
      expect(builds).toEqual([]); // Your expected builds array previously set in spy
    });
});
```

Instead of spying on method which you would like to test we spy on that HttpClient `get` method.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is exactly right. I was so over thinking it. Thanks :) One note, there needs to be another ")" at the very end to close out the inject(

Comment: Take note that in newer version spyOn and Observable.of  need to be writen like this : 
spyOn(httpClient, 'get').and.returnValue(of([*** what need to be pass to your method ***]));